# Can we pass types as parameters to methods?

Tags: scala, types

In scala we can have type members just declaraing `type T`. Can we pass types as method parameters? I tried this:

```
def test(type T)
def test(T: type)
```

but none of them compiled. So, is it possible?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `def test[T]()`?

Comment: @n.m. But we actually have a method with no parameters and one generic type parameter...

Comment: Notice they are called "type parameters". If you are looking for a value representation of a type then you are talking about runtime reflection, e.g. `def f[A](a: A)(implicit tag: scala.reflect.runtime.universe#TypeTag[A]): A`.

Comment: What you are looking for is type-level programming but you are conflating it with value-level programming.

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking whether there's something wrong with it. Would it fail to do something you need your type parameters to do?

Comment: @stella Are you just curious, or are you trying to do something specific? Sending types is common in certain styles of programming, but not so much in functional programming. Perhaps we can suggest a best practice to accomplish your actual goal? Where do you see passing a type as being useful?

Comment: @NathanielFord, "Sending types is common in certain styles of programming, but not so much in functional programming" - are you sure? What about dependent-type languages? And also type function facilities in Haskell?

Comment: @Mika'il I admit no background in Haskell, but I also think that languages which are labelled 'functional' also include non-functional aspects to them: for instance, Scala and OOP. So I was trying to keep it straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to pass types as values to a function in standard Scala.

Also, there are a couple of things wrong with your proposed code:

- Firstly you cannot define a function parameter with the `type` keyword. This is used for declaring type synonyms not the type of a function parameter.
- You cannot even pass a type as a value to a function in Scala. Here you are mixing at one level types in a program and on the other, what are values in your program. Scala functions accept values as arguments to a function (if that function is defined to accept arguments) not types.